# Why does Bundler.require not require dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am developing a gem at the moment. Here's how the `.gemspec` looks like:

```
gem.add_dependency 'activerecord', '~> 4.2'
...

gem.add_development_dependency 'rails', '4.2.5'
...
```

and here's my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec
```

I am setting up my main file, `lib/my_gem.rb` like so:

```
module MyGem
  module Lib
  end
end

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' if File.exist?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
Bundler.require
```

However, if I start `bundle console` from my gem's folder, the dependencies are not required:

```
$ bundle console
Resolving dependencies...
irb(main):001:0> Rails
NameError: uninitialized constant Rails
...
irb(main):002:0> ActiveRecord
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe dependencies included via the `gemspec` command in the `Gemfile` are not automatically required by `Bundler.require`. Only gems listed directly in the `Gemfile` itself are.

Additionally, gems included in only certain Bundler groups, like 'development', may not be required by a `Bundle.require` even if they were included directly in the Gemfile, you need to tell bundler to require groups other than default.

You can always `require` gems manually though, like `require 'rails'`. `Bundle.require` doesn't do anything but `require gem` for each gem in your Gemfile (or at least default group in your Gemfile), it's doing any magic other than looking up all the gems in your Gemfile and requiring them.  `Bundle.require` is considered by some to be a bad practice anyway, you should just require the dependencies you need in the files you need them, some say. Although Rails doesn't agree, and Rails apps have their own somewhat complicated way of auto-loading things.

But if you are in a Rails app, as your example dependencies suggest... why are you doing any `require 'bundler/setup'` or `Bundle.require` yourself at all though, instead of letting Rails boot process take care of it?  Rails boot process will take care of requiring the Bundler groups you probably expect too (like the "development" group when in `Rails.env == 'development'`).

You *can* use the bundler api yourself directly like you're doing, it's not too hard. But Rails ordinarily takes care of this for you, and if you are using Rails, rails probably already has done a `Bundler.setup` and `Bundler.require` as part of Rails boot process.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I'm developing a gem that can be used with and without Rails, and the above question is related to the non-Rails gem usage, that's why I'm doing `Bundler.require`. I find it weird to manually require gems instead of just using Bundler. Why isn't it a best practice to do so? Also, `Bundler.require` will require gems from the default group, and that's the group where `gemspec` puts the `gem_dependency` gems. So I have no clue why those gems aren't properly required by Bundler.